# if I select a text in tree control than how I'll get that message in list control

Tags: mfc

Can anybody tell me, if I select an item in tree control than how I'll get that text in List control at the same time. I am  getting how to do it?
Please help  me out.

Answer (score 2):

When a `CTreeCtrl` has an item selected, there is a `WM_NOTIFY` notification of `TVN_SELCHANGED` - See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/38x8htxs.aspx) for details.

As it also says in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3w4dsefz.aspx) :

> As the user interacts with the control, it will send various
>   notification messages. You can specify a function to handle each of
>   the messages you want to handle by adding an **ON_NOTIFY_REFLECT**
>   macro in your control window's message map or by adding an
>   **ON_NOTIFY** macro to your parent window's message map.

If you do this, you will detect the clicked item, from which you can retrieve the text and add an entry to a list (or whatever else you need to do).

Comment: -I have read that but I am not able to implemented that. I am a student and a beginner on MFC. Please can you write some code that I can understand.

Comment: @GirishJoshi I'm sorry but this is not a "write my code for me" site, you would be better trying to follow some tutorials and, if/when you get stuck, post a short example that demonstrates the problem you have and ask a *specific* question about how to fix it.